# extending a class from an abstract class in java?

Tags: java, java-ee-7

I have below java abstract class.

```
public abstract class Base implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2602178514139825116L;

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

### MainRequest.java

```
public class MainRequest extends Base {

    te static final long serialVersionUID = -1724534962722346709L;


    private String key;
    private String name;


    public MainRequest(String id){
        super.setId(id);
    }

    public MainRequest(String key, String name){
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


}
```

Is my `MainRequest .java` class correct? Do i need to call super class constructor also? Any improvements to MainRequest.java ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see any compilation errors (beside fact that you have `te` instead of `private` in `MainRequest`)?

Comment: nope...i am just asking for any improvement..

Comment: Then better place for such question would be [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Pshemo, sure next time i will post there itself. right now do u suggest any improvemets plz?

Comment: Maybe add constructor for all properties (id, key, name). Anyway your class seems fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review, not specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improvements would be:

- implement a constructor like `Base(String id)` and call it from your `MainRequest` class, so every subclass of `Base` must have an `id` value.

  ```
  public Base(String id) {
      this.id = id;
  }
  ```
- consider using `final` on the `id` member variable in `Base` class and remove the `setId` method. In most cases you don't really want to set an id twice, do you?

  ```
  private final String id;
  ```
- make a constructor like `MainRequest(String id, String key, String name)` to set all things at once like:

  ```
  public MainRequest(String id, String key, String name) {
      super(id);
      this.key = key;
      this.name = name;
  }
  ```
- the use of an `abstract` class is fine, since you're implementing the `getId` method and having a constructor but not want to instantiate this base class at all.
- possible add `final` key word on the `key` and `name` member, if you only want to set these variables once in the constructor (assuming that, because you already have no setter methods):

  ```
  private final String key;
  private final String name;
  ```
- post working code in your question (see `te` => `private`)
- put the question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Of course, some points depending on what you really want to do! But you didn't tell some details about your intention!

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of a case `Base` no need to be `abstract` class it is enough to use an `interface`.

Comment: What if all classes which extends `Base` need to have `id` property? In that case `abstract` class is correct decision.

Comment: Ruchira, Base wil be extended by atleast 10 subclasses...

Answer (score 1):

Inside MainRequest(String key, String name) constructor, no need to use super() constructor. 
You did not use default constructor MainRequest(){ }, so it's jre's responsibility to provide super() inside the parameterized constructor.
You used serializable interface, it has no abstruct method, so while implementing this interface, no headache to define the abstruct methods of that interface. because, it has nothing. (It is called markup interface, aimed to accomplish certain task while IO operation). If you dont pass id value in the parametric constructor, default value of int will be taken by jre.default value is 0. any issues ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing seems strange. If your supper-class has id property, it seems it is usefall for all chiles. So it's not good create a child class without it. So add this to other constructor too:

```
public MainRequest(String id, String key, String name){
    super.setId(id);
    this.key = key;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you make Class Base as abstract?
As you don't have any abstract method no need for the class to be abstract.